# Exel. Смена часового пояса на дате пользователя

Tags: excel

На сайте при формировании отчёта для пользователя в excel попадает часовой пояс сервера (к примеру
26/02/24 08:27:25),  но у пользователя часовой пояс +3, т.е нужно на уровне excel узнать часовой пояс пользователя и изменить дату - в данном случае 26/02/24 11:27:25

Comment: формируйте отчёт правильно. программа excel-то тут при чём?

Comment: Никак на уровне экселя не узнать часовой пояс пользователя. Эксель на сервере, пользователь у себя дома - у экселя нет доступа к пользователю. Из вопроса непонятно как формируется отчет, но надо разницу в часах передавать туда, где формируется этот отчет и учитывать ее.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вижу "На сайте", значит нужно узнавать на сайте часовой пояс пользователя и формировать (корректировать) отчёт соответственно.
2. В отчёт добавить ячейку с часовым поясом, а временные константы в отчёте заменить формулами: та же константа складывается с часовым поясом. Пользователю нужно будет самостоятельно указать свой часовой пояс.